# "My this/that book" vs "this/that book of mine"

Tags: sentence-construction, determiners

I would like to make a sentence like "my that book". For example, if my friend asks me that he wants to take my (that) book and I want to tell him that he can take it. How do I say?

1. My that book?
2. That book of mine?

Now I would like to tell him that he can take that book of mine. We cannot use two adjacent determiners so I cannot say "my that book". But how do I use "that" and "my" in the same sentence?

3. You can take that book of mine?
4. You can take my that book?

Sentences number 1 and 4 are not possible because they use adjacent determiners. Do the other sentences sound idiomatic?

In short, if I want to use "that" (for indication) and "my" (for possession), how do I tell my friend that he can take my book?

Comment: If your friend has asked your permission, he knows the book he wants is yours. All you need to ask is "That one?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in many cases we'd use **the**.

If we were referring to it immediately after the other person had asked for it, then saying "**it**" makes sense, as another answer suggested.

But say that you requested it earlier in the conversion, or when we last met, and as you're about to leave, I want to give it to you.  I might say "Here's **the** book" or "Here's **the** book you wanted".

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only valid expression is

> that book of mine

But it's not idiomatic in the context that you have described. It sounds odd.

Notice that your friend have already stated **which** book he/she desire (indication) and that it **belongs to you** (possession). There's no need for you to repeat those traits again in your answer.

> -- Can you lend me **your Bible**, please?
> -- Yes, of course, take **it**.

"Your Bible" - where "Bible" can be replaced by any other title that you own - is already pointing that the book is yours and which one of your books he/she wants.

I have also highlighted the pronoun **it**. That word represents what you're looking for: "that book of mine". It's a bit redundant and verbose if you reply: "Yes, you can take that book of mine".

Answer (score 0):

If the book is obvious, you just say *you can take my book*, and it will mean that one. Otherwise you may need something like *You can take my copy of that book*.